# Logstash не принимает данные из XML файла

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

XMLфайл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        -<Documents xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://localhost/request">
 <Document>
       <Status>Зарегистрировано</Status>
        <Number>000000001</Number>
        <Tip>Внутренняя</Tip>
        </Document>
<Document>
    <Status>Исполнено</Status>
        <Number>000000002</Number>
        <Tip>Внешняя</Tip>
        </Document>

    <Document>
        <Status>Зарегистрировано</Status>
        <Number>000000003</Number>
        <Tip>Внешняя</Tip>
        </Document>
       <Document>
        <Status>Исполнено</Status>
        <Number>000000004</Number>
        <Tip>Внутренняя</Tip>
        </Document>
          <Document>
        <Status>Зарегистрировано</Status>
        <Number>000000005</Number>
        <Tip>Внешняя</Tip>
        </Document>
           -<Document>
        <Status>Зарегистрировано</Status>
        <Number>000000006</Number>
        <Tip>Внутренняя</Tip>
        </Document>
           <Document>
        <Status>Зарегистрировано</Status>
        <Number>000000007</Number>
        <Tip>Внутренняя</Tip>
        </Document>
        <Document>
        <Status>Зарегистрировано</Status>
        <Number>000000008</Number>
        <Tip>Внешняя</Tip>
        </Document>
        </Documents>
```

Мой config Logstash

```
  input {
 file {
    path =>"D:/ElasticMain/1C/servicesdeskxml.xml"
    start_position => beginning
    type => "document"
    codec => multiline
    {
        pattern => "^<\?Document .*\>"
        negate => true
        what => "previous"
    }
 }
}
filter {
        xml {
        source => "document"
        xpath =>
        [
            "/documents/document/status/text()", "document_status", 
            "/documents/document/number/text()", "document_number",
            "/documents/document/tip/text()", "document_tip"
   ]
   store_xml => true
   target => "doc"
}
}

output {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
elasticsearch {
        index => "logstash-xml"
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        document_type => "document"
 }
}
```

Логи в Logstash

```
[2019-08-28T10:10:22,479][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"testxml", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[2019-08-28T10:10:22,854][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[2019-08-28T10:10:23,042][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[2019-08-28T10:10:23,104][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>6}
[2019-08-28T10:10:23,104][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
[2019-08-28T10:10:23,136][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]}
[2019-08-28T10:10:23,136][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2019-08-28T10:10:23,167][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2019-08-28T10:10:24,870][INFO ][logstash.inputs.file     ] No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the "path" setting {:sincedb_path=>"C:/ElasticSearch/logstash-6.6.0/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_45ebfa0d1a4c252cd358ba2e28760f4d", :path=>["D:/ElasticMain/1C/servicesdeskxml.xml"]}
[2019-08-28T10:10:24,917][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"testxml", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x5c0ce9a2 sleep>"}
[2019-08-28T10:10:24,964][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:testxml], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2019-08-28T10:10:24,995][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2019-08-28T10:10:25,339][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

Logstash прекращает работу дальше не двигается 
Index не создается в Elastic
Не могу понять в чем дело?! 
Где то есть ошибки в конфиге?

Comment: Документ xml содержит какие-то знаки "-" перед тегами `<Document>`. Это вы скопипастили откуда-то или они действительно существуют в файле?

Comment: В файле не было просто копировался